# Error while using ActiveMQ PooledConnectionFactory

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-commons-pool

I am using ActiveMQ PooledConnectionFactory

```
PooledConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(Constants.AAMQ_MESSAGE_BROKER_URI);
Connection tempConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection(queueUName, queuePwd);
```

its generating following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.setLifo(Z)V   at
>   org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:213)
>     at
>   com.model.util.MyJMSClient.createNewConnection(MyJMSClient.java:393)
>     at com.model.util.MyJMSClient.getConnection(MyJMSClient.java:386)   at
>   com.model.util.MyJMSClient.executeCommandASync(MyJMSClient.java:179)
>     at com.model.util.MyJMSClient.executeCommand(MyJMSClient.java:104)
>     at
>   com.model.util.WinCommandRunner.executeCommand(WinCommandRunner.java:99)

i have common-pool and other libs in the classspath

Comment: what version of activemq are you using?

Comment: activemq 5.8.0 and commons-pool 1.6

Comment: all i can think of is to print your classpath.  could there be an older version of commons-pool on your classpath?